# if i have 2 cell arrays 1 containing user names & the other containing coordinate. how can the 1st name equals the 1st coordinate & so on?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

If I have 2 cell arrays in matlab one containing user names and the other containing coordinate, how can i make the first name equals the first coordinate and so on ? for example i want user1=[xR1 yR1],....,user50=[xR50 yR50], so when i want to use coordinate [xR1 yR1] i call user1 .So how this could be done ?
this is the code for the 2 cell arrays

```
user = cell(50,50);
name=cell(size(user,2),1);
 for i=1:size(user,2)
           name{i}=['user ',num2str(i)];
 end
users = cell(50, 1);


for i=1:50
users{i} =[xR(i) yR(i)];
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
sz = 50;
user = cell(sz, 1);
name = cell(sz, 1);
for i=1:sz
    name{i} = ['user_', num2str(i)];
    user{i} = rand(1, 2);
end

for i=1:sz
    eval([name{i} '= user{i}']);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid cluttering up the workspace with 50 such variables. I would rather prefer to have a `struct` that has the fieldnames as the `User IDs`. The following code is a demo for `5` such User IDs, which you can extend to `50` -

```
%%// X-Y Coordinates
coords = randi(5,5,2); %%// random data

%%// User IDs
user_ids = cell(size(coords,1),1);
for i=1:size(coords,1)
    user_ids{i}=['user',num2str(i)];
end

%%// Combined cell array to store X-Y coordinates and User IDs
all_data = cell2struct(num2cell(coords), user_ids, 1);
```

**How to use:** If you would like to access `user4` data, use this - `vertcat(all_data.user4)'`